# tex4ebook with error while using footnotemark in MWE.tex

Tags: footnotes, tex4ebook

With the following MWE an error is occuring while runnig tex4ebook: `The "a" element cannot contain any nested "a" elements.`

How do footnotes work in E-Books?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\usepackage{tex4ebook}

\begin{document}
A sentence\footnote[3]{Some footnotetext}

Another sentence\footnotemark[3]    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the default footnote handling. It inserts nested link in footnote mark, which leads to this problem. Try this config file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

\catcode`\:=11
        \Configure{footnotetext}
   {\ifTag{fn\FNnum x\minipageNum
}
   {\expandafter\ifx\csname (fn\FNnum x\minipageNum
)\endcsname\def
       \:warning{Multiple footnote texts for mark \FNnum}%
    \else \csname a:footnote-text\endcsname\fi
   }
   {}%
%
    \csname a:footnote-mark\endcsname
\AnchorLabel
\Link{}{fn\FNnum x\minipageNum
}%
    \NoFonts%
   }
   {\EndNoFonts \EndLink\csname b:footnote-mark\endcsname
}
   {\ifTag{fn\FNnum x\minipageNum
}
   {\expandafter\ifx\csname (fn\FNnum x\minipageNum
)\endcsname\def
    \else  \csname b:footnote-text\endcsname\fi
   }
   {}%
\expandafter\global\expandafter
   \let\csname (fn\FNnum x\minipageNum
)\endcsname\def
}
\catcode`\:=12

\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Comment: Thank you, Michal. The result is now a valid epub file run with epubcheck. - BUT: I got another problem: The index with the package `sanitize-umlaut` seems not compatible with `tex4ebook`. Maybe I ask another question?